# LC_ALL='C' equivalent for windows using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, locale

I am trying to find an equivalent implementation for `LC_ALL='C'` for Windows using powershell..

Following is my snippet of code in shell which i am supposed to port for powershell.

```
for d in $(func1 paramter); do
    ...
    ...
done | LC_ALL=C sort
```

I have tried the following:

```
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')
Get-Content -Encoding Ascii "a.txt" | Sort-Object -Culture $culture
```

assuming `a.txt` has data to be sorted!!

Comment: You can increase the number of people who can potentially answer you, by explaining what LC_ALL=C means. Specifying the language you are trying to translate *from* might also help this objective. Not everyone proficient with powershell also knows whatever that thing you are trying to translate from.

Answer (score 0):

How does your data look like? If its a table structure, include a column for sorting in your sort-object statement.

Also, if you want your data to be saved into a.txt you should pipe it to a set-content statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the equivalent of `set LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` in PowerShell and found out that it was `$env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'`. So try this:

`$env:LC_ALL='C'`

Comment: `LC_ALL` is a \*nix thing so setting that variable in Windows won't work